# Set.point in python 2.7 io

Tags: python, io

I was wondering if there was something inside python io, so that when a file is opened in say a+ you could set the pointer to a specific point and start writing

Comment: What do you mean by "specific point"? `a+` will read from the start but write to the end.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `f.seek(position)` (docs for [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) and [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)):

```
with open('file.txt', 'a+') as f:
    f.seek(10)
    f.write("New data")
```

Here, you skip over the first 10 bytes and then write the new data. Note that there is also an optional second argument `whence` that allows you to specify whether `position` should be relative to the beginning of the file, the current location within the file, or the end of the file. See the documentation links above for more information.